# Overwriting next method of custom iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator

I would like to know how to, if possible, overwrite the `next()` method of a custom iterator. For example, I have a function that returns a iterator:

```
function myFunction(...args) {
  return {
    async next() {
      // Lazy!
      const id = await resource.getId(...args)

      console.log('first')
      // After first call, overwrite the next!
      this.next = async () => {
        console.log('second')
        // with id, do other thing
        const value = await resource2.getOtherThing(id)
        if (value.property) return { done: false, value }
        return { done: true, value } 
      }
      return this.next()
    }

    [Symbol.asyncIterator] {
      return this
    }
  }
}
```

But this is not really being overwritted, because the `first` is appearing in every loop:

```
for await (const x of myFunction(...) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does `second` appear then?

Comment: Yes, `first` and `second` always appears..

Comment: @seethrough any ideias?

Comment: oh, I though this post was deleted, sorry. so  what is the `this` referring to in this function? what is the context

Comment: it's referring to itself I believe... let my check it!

Comment: yes, it's referring to itself.

Comment: the problem is that I can't reproduce it. can you create some kind of jsfiddle or anything of that type.Sorry that it took me this long since last comment

Comment: Yes, I can, just give me 1 second..

Comment: @seethrough you need to use node > 10 to test it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKdyGm

Comment: @seethrough are you still there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172366/discussion-between-seethrough-and-alokx).

Comment: so it is not resolvable?

Comment: @seethrough no :/.